# How to pause js function until user presses the button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have an html button on my site and I want my js function to stop until user presses it. `onclick="nextFunction()"` doesn't help me because I need to continue in the same function. What should I do?

Comment: That's a very broad and generic question. Seeing the code would help...

Comment: I think you need to provide an [mcve]-- without it the question is so broad that no really meaningful advice can be given.

Comment: Consider making 2 functions. Run the first and only run the second after button press.